# How to pass a ZnClient as parameter to a method?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

Basically I have a method that return a ZnClient logged. I want to create another method that take this ZnClient as parameter. How can we do it in pharo?

Comment: I don't understand. If you create a method that takes a parameter, you can pass anything, Smalltalk is a dynamic language. You just make a method in the appropriate class.

Comment: Ah, wait... Do you have any classes? Or are you doing things in the Workspace? You should describe a bit what you have, how are you doing things. And what you want to do

Comment: Yes I was trying on the workspace. and now I have just created a class with these two methods.As you said I can pass anything. I just figured out. Sorry I am new in pharo and I was just wondering about the syntax @fedes.

Comment: Oh, it's ok! I figured you are new, but not what the problem was. Just keep it up, Smalltalk is a nice little jewel among programming languages. It's got very few and simple rules.

Comment: yes like you said a nice little jewel. Thanks :)